# Optimizing Performance - Large File Input in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, shiny-reactivity

I have a function (clawCheck) defined in the file CheckClawback.R which takes three data frames as arguments. In my Shiny app, the user uploads three files which are then read into memory and used as the ClawCheck arguments. In order to save time, I want R to start reading a file into memory as soon as it is uploaded, and not only after the "GO" button is pressed, so that once the button is pressed, the arguments for ClawCheck are already in memory and ready to use.

I'm thinking that I have to use eventReactive expressions within the renderTable statement, since I don't want the files to be re-read every time a user changes some input. To avoid further complication, I assume the input is filled in in order, i.e first "account", then "commpaid", then "termriders". When I run the app and the first input file has been uploaded, there is no progress bar appearing which indicates that my code is not working correctly. Here is my (reduced) code:

```
library('shiny')

source("CheckClawback.R")

ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      fileInput("account", "Account File (.csv)"), 

      fileInput("commpaid", "CommPaid File (.txt)"), 

      fileInput("termriders", "TermRiders File (.txt)"), 

      actionButton("do", "GO!")),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("out_table"))
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {


  func <- eventReactive(input$do, {

    req(acc)
    req(comm)
    req(term)

    datat <<- clawCheck(acc, comm, term)

  })


  output$out_table <- renderTable({

    eventReactive(input$account, {

      withProgress(message = "Preparing Account Data...Please Wait", {

      acc <<- read.csv(input$account$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ",")

      })
    })

    eventReactive(input$commpaid, {

      withProgress(message = "Preparing CommPaid Data...Please Wait", {

        comm <<- read.table(input$commpaid$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = "\t")

      })
    })

    eventReactive(input$termriders, {

      withProgress(message = "Preparing TermRiders Data...Please Wait", {

        term <<- read.table(input$termriders$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = "\t")

      })
    })

    withProgress(func(), message = "Loading Output...Please Wait")

    datat
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Ideally, after a file is uploaded, a progress bar should appear, indicating that it is being processed. If, during this process, a second file is uploaded, a second progress bar should appear, indicating that the second file is being processed etc. Once the actual function call happens, I want the input files to be ready to go.

I am very thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `<<-` and `withProgress()` is wrong. Also, using `eventReactive()` inside a `render*()` is wrong. I suggest going through RStudio Shiny tutorials to get help on understanding how *reactivity* works. Also look at `showNotification()` instead of `withProgress()`. For now, here's what you probably need -

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  acc <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$account), "acc not uploaded")
    # use showNotification(); use same approach for other files
    read.csv(input$account$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
    # use removeNotification() to remove mesg after file is uploaded
  })

  comm <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$commpaid), "comm not uploaded")
    read.table(input$commpaid$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
  })

  term <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$termriders), "term not uploaded")
    read.table(input$termriders$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
  })


  func <- eventReactive(input$do, {
    clawCheck(acc(), comm(), term())
  })


  output$out_table <- renderTable({
    func()
  })

}
```

Comment: thank you for your help! I apologise for my clumsy use of shiny expressions - this is my first time working with shiny. I'm still having a hard time getting my head around reactivity but if I understand correctly, acc is updated only if one of its reactive dependencies (i.e. input$account) change and by making acc reactive, anything dependent on acc will update anytime acc changes etc?? One problem I am experiencing is that the validation error messages don't show even if I leave all inputs empty and just press "GO"...do you have any idea where that could come from? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Leon231000 First of all no need to apologize. Just go through the RStudio tutorials in order and you'll be fine.You are right about the reactivity of `acc`. For validation mesg, see if my updated code works.